# Chrome Dev tools not refreshing with Gulp-Sass

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, gulp

I write most of my CSS in Chrome dev tools, so that the browser will watch for changes to the files and will refresh appropriately. I have recently switched from Compass to Gulp-Sass for compiling my SCSS, but Chrome no longer refreshes upon changes. If I swap out Gulp-Sass for Gulp-Ruby-Sass in my Gulpfile, Chrome will refresh.

I really want to stick with Gulp-Sass/libsass since it compiles so much faster and I don't want a Ruby dependency, but I can't figure out what I need to do to make Gulp-Sass fit in with my workflow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sassdoc = require('sassdoc');

var sass_options = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
};

gulp.task('sass-app', function(){
    return gulp.src('./static/sass/styles.scss')
               .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
               .pipe(sass(sass_options).on('error', sass.logError))
               .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
               // .pipe(rename('styles.css'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass-all', function() {
    return gulp.src('./static/sass/**/*.scss')
               .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
               .pipe(sass(sass_options).on('error', sass.logError))
               .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass-app'], function(){
    gulp.watch('./static/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass-app']);
});

gulp.task('watch-all', ['sass-all'], function (){
    gulp.watch('./static/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass-all']);
});
```

Comment: Please look at Browsersync as a viable option to use with your Gulp operations

Comment: I've tried Browsersync but haven't been able to get it's proxies to work with my server set-up.

Comment: From what I read, you are mostly concerned with Chrome Dev Tools, it is not that your changes are not loading on the browser anymore. Or perhaps it is the fact that your new setup is broken, can you clarify?

Comment: No, I don't think my set up is broken. Everything compiles correctly sourcemaps are in the right place. Chrome just isn't refreshing upon CSS changes. I'll add my gulpfile if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Browsersync](http://www.browsersync.io/)

Here's a sample code that may help with your problem with the proxy

```
gulp.task('watch-all', ['sass-all'], function (){
   browserSync.init({
       proxy: "http://localhost/project_name" 
   });

   gulp.watch('./static/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass-all']);
});
```